# How to capture a frame from a camera stream exactly when a key is hit using opencv in python?

Tags: python, video, opencv, camera, video-capture

I am trying to capture image from a webcam when a key is hit. Following code is successful

```
    import cv

    cv.NamedWindow("w1")
    camera = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)

    while True:

        key = cv.WaitKey(0);

        if key == 'q': 
            break;
        image = cv.QueryFrame(camera)
        cv.ShowImage("w1", image)


    cv.DestroyWindow("w1")
```

It works fine for the first keypress. For the next keydown it shows a frame very close to the first one even if you moved. After several key presses it changes to the actual image. What i can infer is that, there is some kind of buffer where frames are stored
I am wondering if someone could please help me in getting the precise frame when a key is being hit.

I am using opencv with interface to python. The operating system is ubuntu 11.04. The calls for capture frame are sent to v4l library. I have an integrated webcam with my dell laptop.

I am wondering if someone can help me with this issue.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try it in a slightly different manner:

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow("w1")
camera = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)

while True:
    image = cv.QueryFrame(camera)
    key = cv.WaitKey(33)

    if key == 'q':
        break
    elif key != -1:
        cv.ShowImage("w1", image)

cv.DestroyWindow("w1")
```

Notice the change in the call to cv.WaitKey(): instead of blocking on it, just wait for a reasonable time. Then check if a key was actually pressed (key != -1).

I should note that your code worked on my Mac OS X 10.6 with OpenCV 2.3.

Comment: @ cesarbs, it is a nice way of doing it but the problem is that we will be retrieving frames continually which will off course put burden on the system. Do you have any idea of doing it with continuous retrieval? Thanks a lot.